# Main cannot be resolved or is not a field, R.layout.main (Tried other methods)

Tags: android

I've searched for this but I hasn't worked for me. I tried a lot. I've cleaned project, added com.package.name.R. I still get the error after cleaning. I really need help on this since I'm new to Android developing. Please make it understandable for me. Thanks and here is the code:

```
package com.gunnarco.gunnarscalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.gunnarco.gunnarscalculator.R;

public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity {

 public String str ="";
 Character op = 'q';
 int i,num,numtemp;
    EditText showResult;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        showResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result_id);
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



 <EditText

    android:id="@+id/result_id"  

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="120dp"

  />
```

Comment: what is the name of that xml file you posted? Have you went through EVERY xml file to be sure there are NO errors, even in `manifest.xml`?

Comment: The one I posted was the activity_calculator or I think it is also the main.xml. Its located in res/layout. I only went through the xml i posted. It doesn't show any errors. I need more guide as I'm new to this. Thanks.

Comment: try to create a new project and take a look at how a basic project constructed. Comparing with your project, I think you can find out what's wrong here

Comment: Ok I will try what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the layout file you posted is `main.xml`. (If it isn't, then that's your problem. The name of each layout file is used to name the fields of `R.layout`.)

If I'm correct and that is your entire `main.xml` file, then it has an error: you don't have a closing tag for `<RelativeLayout ...>`. If you have an error in any of your XML files, then the resource compiler will not generate an R.java file and you will have unresolved field errors.

As an aside, you don't need to import your `R` class in code that is in your application package (as declared in the manifest).

Comment: I don't see a main.xml file. I have a activity_calculator.xml. That's the xml that I posted.

Comment: Then that's your problem.  The statement `setContentView(R.layout.main);` tells the system to build a View hierarchy from **main.xml**. If there's no **main.xml** file, then your app will fail. Perhaps you should call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);` instead.

Comment: Cool, I have no errors but I have lots of warnings and when I try to run the project on my device it says in the console: [2013-08-05 18:10:23 - Gunnar'sCalculator] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2013-08-05 18:10:23 - Gunnar'sCalculator] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-08-05 18:10:23 - Gunnar'sCalculator] Launch canceled!

Comment: @GunnarBates - So what's in the logcat? Also, did you try running on an emulator first? If so, what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

> The one I posted was the activity_calculator

If so then that's your problem. Change your `onCreate()` to use that file

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
```

You are trying to `inflate` a `layout` file that doesn't exist so you get this error. `setContentView()` inflates, or shows for imports for lack of a better word, the `layout` to be used with this `Activity`. Every `View` (`Button`, `EditText`, etc..) you access for this `Activity` should be in this file, in basic circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding what has happened on your android project, I suggest you can create a new project and try to build it successfully first. Because you don't have too much code here, you can add your code one by one until everything done successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any files, pictures, etc in your drawable or assets folder with capital letters, spaces, or dashes. Just use plane old lowercase. Also, try to clean your project. Go to project > clean. Then restart eclipse. Hope this helps. Also eclipse won't reconize any changes in XML files without saving first. Make sure to save after you add a button, ect